# Fetching data into an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a file like this below:

```
-bash-4.2$ cat a1.txt
0        10.95.187.87  5444  up      0.333333   primary  0           false  0            
1        10.95.187.88  5444  up      0.333333   standby  1           true   0            
2        10.95.187.89  5444  up      0.333333   standby  0           false  0
```

I want to fetch the data from the above file into a 2D array.
Can you please help me with a suitable way to put into an array.
Also post putting we need put a condition to check whether the value in the 4th column is UP or DOWN. If it's UP then OK, if its down then below command needs to be executed.

```
-bash-4.2$ pcp_attach_node -w -U pcpuser -h localhost -p 9898 0
```

(The value at the end is getting fetched from the 1st column.

Comment: Its for EDB postgres and a pgpool utility.

Comment: I just want to understand the logic on to implementing that in array which I am not able to find it out. Can you please guide me to get the logic code to complete my script please.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name .. please forget about postgres and connecting to the databases. I just have a text file and from their I want to put data in the array and fetch it from there. can you please help me with the logic to implement the same.

Comment: The text file has the data in the tabular format as specified above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think you can have 2D arrays in bash. But you can however store lines into a 1-D array.

Here is a script ,parse1a.sh, to demonstrate emulation of 2D arrays for the type of data you included:

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_element ()  {
  line=${ARRAY[$1]}
  echo $line | awk "{print \$$(($2+1))}" #+1 since awk is one-based
}

function set_element ()  {
  line=${ARRAY[$1]}
  declare -a SUBARRAY=($line)
  SUBARRAY[$(($2))]=$3
  ARRAY[$1]="${SUBARRAY[@]}"
}

ARRAY=()
while IFS='' read -r line ||  [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    #echo $line
    ARRAY+=("$line")
done < "$1"

echo "Full array contents printout:"
printf "%s\n" "${ARRAY[@]}" # Full array contents printout.

for line in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    #echo $line
    if [ "$(echo $line | awk '{print $4}')" == "down" ]; then
        echo "Replace this with what to do for down"
    else
        echo "...and any action for up - if required"
    fi
done

echo "Element access of [2,3]:"
echo "get_element 2 3 : "
get_element 2 3
echo "set_element 2 3 left: "
set_element 2 3 left
echo "get_element 2 3 : "
get_element 2 3

echo "Full array contents printout:"
printf "%s\n" "${ARRAY[@]}" # Full array contents printout.
```

It can be executed by:

```
./parsea1 a1.txt
```

Hope this is close to what you are looking for. Note that this code will loose all indenting spaces during manipulation, but a formatted update of the lines could solve that.

Comment: In each of the scripts below I am getting either the complete line or complete column when echo'ing. I want to control each and every record, not the line or column

Comment: I think the use case you describe would be easier by just parsing the lines with awk. However, I update my example to show how you could emulate 2-D array manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
while read -r line; do
  declare -a array=( $line ) # use IFS
  echo "${array[0]}"
  echo "${array[1]}" # and so on
  if [[ "$array[3]" ]]; then 
    echo execute command...
  fi
done < a1.txt
```

Or:

```
while read -r -a array; do
  if [[ "$array[3]" ]]; then 
    echo execute command...
  fi
done < a1.txt
```

This works only if field are space separated (any kind of space).

You could probably mix that with regexp if you need more precise control of the format.

Comment: I suggest to replace `-r line` with `-r -a array` and delete line with `declare`. See: `help read`

Comment: Did not know that one. I left mine because you may change the IFS.

Comment: while read -r line; do
  declare -a array=( $line ) # use IFS
  echo "${array[0]}"
  echo "${array[1]}"
  echo "${array[2]}"
  echo "${array[3]}"
done < a1.txt.. I executed this one and the o/p cpomes like as below:

Comment: 0
10.95.187.87
5444
up
1
10.95.187.88
5444
up
2
10.95.187.89
5444
up

Comment: If you want to do `array=($line)` then you need to `set -f` -- consider what happens if one of the fields is `*`